# get date by $_get and wants to show in form having input type date in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I wants to edit a data line in php. In thar line there is a field "date". when i want to get it display in my edit page (in which other data is showing by using $_GET, date is not showing, when I chang "INPUT TYPE=DATE" into "INPUT TYPE=TEXT" it also start working.
(i want to use it in "Update/Edit privisaly enter date")
My Code is

```
**not working =>**
<?php $SSS = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($_GET['FDATE'])); ?> 
<td><input type="date" class="txt1" name="FDATE" value="<?php echo $SSS; ?>" /></td>


**Working =>**
<?php $SSS = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($_GET['FDATE'])); ?> 
<td><input type="text" class="txt1" name="FDATE" value="<?php echo $SSS; ?>" /></td>
```

Comment: if you want to use input type=date try using $date = new \DateTime($_GET['FDATE']); then you can format as a string like $date->format('d-m-Y');

Comment: also not related but type="date" is not supported in Safari or Internet Explorer 11 (or earlier).

Comment: then what is the best option for this which support all